# Trigger Databricks Delta Live Tables Pipeline from Synapse

Tags: databricks, azure-synapse, delta-live-tables

We would like to trigger and run a Databricks Delta Live Tables Pipeline from an Azure Synapse pipeline which creates a couple of bronze and silver tables.

[image]

I cant find any info on that.

However, it is possible to run Databricks notebooks in Synapse pipelines.

[image]

So second best would be, to run a Datatbricks notebook from Synapse. But how can I triger a Delta Live Tables pipeline from a Databricks notebook then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call dlt pipeline by using databricks notebook in synapse pipeline,
but what you can do is call web activity which can be triggered manually.

Follow below steps.

First, add a schedule to your dlt pipeline.

[image]

After, clicking on **Add a schedule** you will get below
options.

[image]

Add **Job name**, check **Schedule** as **Manual**
and then click on create.

Next, go these created job under **Workflows**.

[image]

There, copy the **Job Id**.

Now, in synapse pipeline add **Web activity** and add below details as shown in image.

1. **URL** =   `https://<Your_databricks_url>/api/2.1/jobs/run-now`
2. **METHOD** = **POST**
3. **Body** = `{ "job_id": "Job_id" }` Add job id you copied before.
4. **Headers** = **Authorization** as  `Bearer <Your_databricks_token>` and **Content-Type** as `application/json`

[image]

After adding all those details call the web activity.

Output:

[image]

You will get return response having **run_id**.

[image]